# Missing Data (Event Matching System)

Tags: python, datetime, pattern-matching, latitude-longitude, missing-data

I am working in an event matching system and i have a large dataset of pairs of events. Each pair of events has 2 titles, 2 venues, 2 start dates; 2 latitude/longitude coordinates pairs, etc.

Some of the information is missing,( for example, start dates set to 00:00:00, latitude values are 0, etc).
I have done a quick analysis on my dataset and i have 964 pairs out of 2090 ( around 46%) with at least one slot with missing data.

How should i deal with this missing data? What is the best way to not lose information in the process and jeopardize my analysis?
Should i use a library like pandas(http://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: Could you give a few pairs as an example and show what you want to happen to them?

Comment: pair of events with: latitude1: 0 ; longitude1: x.xxxxx; latitude2: 0; longitude2: xxx.xxxxx. Starttime1: 14:00:00 , Starttime2: 00:00:00. There are pairs of events in which i got the name of the 1st venue/adress but i got 'None' as the second.  I would like to know a clever way to deal with this missing data in those three different cases before applying metrics, normalization, etc. Thanks in advance.